# DB2, Java: Can not CREATE TABLE conditionally

Tags: java, sql, exception, if-statement, db2

I'm trying to create a table within an IF-THEN-ELSE statement in Java.
Here is what i've tried so far:

```
stmt.execute(
                "BEGIN IF (SELECT tabname FROM syscat.tables WHERE tabname = 'KUNDENKONTAKTDATEN' and tabschema = 'GRP35') IS NULL THEN "
                + "CREATE TABLE KundenKontaktDaten(Kunden_Nr INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Twitter_Id VARCHAR(40), Google_Id BIGINT, Facebook_Id BIGINT, Skype_Id VARCHAR(64), Telefonnummer VARCHAR(50));"
                + "ELSE "
                + "DELETE FROM KundenKontaktDaten; "
                + "END IF;"
                + "END");
```

Running this one i always get the following exception:

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=KEY;INT NOT NULL PRIMARY;<references_spec>, DRIVER=4.13.80
```

Removing NOT NULL and PRIMARY KEY from Kunden_Nr returns the following exception:

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=<ddl-statement>, DRIVER=4.13.80
```

Does anyone has any idea how to handle that one?

greets

Comment: You could move the logic to the java side.

Comment: Sadly, prof wants us to use sql statements instead.

Answer (score 0):

Most DDL statements, including `CREATE TABLE`, cannot be compiled in a stand-alone compound SQL (what you might call an anonymous block). You will need to execute it dynamically:

```
stmt.execute(
    "BEGIN IF (SELECT tabname FROM syscat.tables WHERE tabname = 'KUNDENKONTAKTDATEN' and tabschema = 'GRP35') IS NULL THEN "
  + "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE KundenKontaktDaten (...)';"
  + ...
```

Comment: Yep, already tried that one. Doesn't work as well. :-( Finally i moved the logic to java and got it to work. Thanks for your answers!